# Hadoop Error "Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1"

Tags: python, hadoop, mrjob, bigdata

`mapper.py` is working fine. I ran `mapper.py` on my cluster and stored its output in `part-0.txt`.

Excatly like a word-count job, I am trying to count the occurrences of every distinct key stored in `part-0.txt` file.

I tried copy-pasting the code from this link:
http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/

It worked but I was unable to understand it's reducer code, so I wrote my own reducer.

And here is the reducer **code**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from numpy import *
import sys

arr = []
previous_printed_word = ''
#f=open('/home/nalin/Downloads/part-0.txt','r')

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    current_word, current_count = line.split('\t',1)
    current_count = 0

    if(previous_printed_word != current_word):
        #f2 = open('/home/nalin/Downloads/part-0.txt', 'r')
        for line2 in sys.stdin:
            line2 = line2.strip()
            word, count2 = line2.split('\t', 1)
            count2 = int(count2)
            if current_word == word:
                current_count = current_count + count2
            else:
                continue
        print '%s\t\t\t%d' % (current_word, current_count-1)
        arr.append ( [current_word, current_count-1] )
        previous_printed_word = current_word

arr = sorted(arr, key=lambda row: row[1])
#print arr
length=len(arr)
print "LENGHT OF 2-D ARRAY IS = ",length
for i in range(1,11):
    print arr[length-i]
```

I keep getting this **error**:

```
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
```

I tried looking up what this error means and I found out that this error comes up when there is something wrong with the code.

But if I uncomment out these 2 lines:

```
f = open('/home/nalin/Downloads/part-0.txt', 'r')

f2 = open('/home/nalin/Downloads/part-0.txt', 'r')
```

put `f` & `f2` instead of `sys.stdin`(on both occurrences of sys.stdin) then it works like a charm.

It is working when I run it on mappers output file. 
It is not working when I run it on my cluster.

Help me figure out what is wrong in the code.

Comment: How are you executing the job?

Comment: using this command:

 bin/hadoop \
    jar /home/nalin/hadoop-2.7.3/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.7.3.jar \
    -mapper "python /home/nalin/PycharmProjects/ForHadoop/ml_1n_mapper.py" \
    -reducer "python /home/nalin/PycharmProjects/ForHadoop/ml_1n_reducer.py" \
    -input "/input4/ratings.dat" \
    -output "wordcount12"